# php how to write data into json?

Tags: php, json

I am newer for php. I want make php page cache, query data from mysql and store data into json format.

I have many questions:

1. which type of file should I store? `.json` or `.txt` or `.cache`? for I also need use json decode return datas into page.
2. I want use cron tab, make many mysql queries and write into one json file. what write code should I choose? `fopen, fwrite` or `file_get_contents` or other command? (do not cover the data, but continue write. I will deleted the file and renewer it at the next cron time)
3. If a multi write into a json data (10 or more mysql query at the same time and write into a same json file, each json child format like `{name: ".$row['name']."}`), how to completed a top `{` and bottom `}` to make a standad json data format?

   **{** //how to add this one

   {name: ".$row['name']."}

   {name: ".$row['name']."}

   // many name from 10 more mysql queries

   **}** //and this one

Thanks.

Comment: What's a PHP page cache to you? Pre-generated static HTML content?

Comment: Don't build your own cache, especially if you're newer to PHP. Use one of the MANY other systems already built. But I'll say this right now: JSON is not a good data storage format for arbitrary/random access. Either you're doing risky string manipulation on the raw JSON string, or you're decoding/manipulating/re-encoding, at which point you've probably killed any savings from cacheing the data.

Comment: **Don't** generate your own JSON strings!  Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which type of file should I store

It doesn't matter. There is no fixed extension, but I would pick `.json` just to make it clear what the file is supposed to contain.

> what write code should I choose?

Just use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to put the JSON string (see next section) into a file.

> each json child format like

You **really** do not want to use that method. It might work for a while, but becomes very complex when you need to handle things like quoting and special-character escapes. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, use PHP's built-in [JSON functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) for this.

Create the data-structure you want using PHP's strings, numbers, and arrays, and then rely on `json_encode` to turn it into a string.

The main thing to be careful of is that depending on how your php `array()` looks, you might get JSON `[]` versus `{}`.

Comment: thanks reply. I write into 10 different pages for a faster mysql query and file write, so how to make `array()`? one page is completed a `{ }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 7):

It's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php)

> json_encode() — Returns the JSON representation of a value

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as saving the file as .txt or .json won't make a difference.
2. I think the focal point of this all lies in the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) page. Here's the example from that page:

This code:

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Outputs like this:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

3 . You can use [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to write to your file. The second argument to fopen is the mode, you want to use 'a' for append.

Comment: hi in your `$arr` code, this one will make a completed json files. but I will write 10 more json data into one file at the same time. (I write into 10 different page for a faster finish)

Comment: @fish man Are you asking if you can put arrays in JSON? If so, the answer is yes. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own cache because anything you write in PHP will be slower than can be supported by native extensions (like APC or memcached or even MySQL itself!!).

Don't cache as JSON. JSON is not a particulary 'fast' to serialize. If you're doing caching you don't want to do any serialization at all. Just store it as it is.

MySQL does query caching for you. If performance is a problem first tune your MySQL queries and database schema. Caching is one of the absolute *last* optimization you want to do.

If you want an easy way to cache, make a MySQL table called 'cache' and use that. If you want quick (small) file access, use MySQL (seriously). If you want an even faster cache access use an in-memory cache like APC or memcached.

Comment: `Don't cache as JSON.` @Frits van Campen, so how about `xml`?

Comment: XML is even worse. Why would you even want a human readable cache? :D